# Adding 2nd wifi connection to laptop with wifi already built in

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I have a 1 year old Asus laptop (model UX31) running Windows 7 which has a frequent problem with the wifi that I've never gotten to the bottom of (https://superuser.com/questions/494241/asus-ux31-wifi-kills-netgears-router-wireless-signal).

If I turn off the inbuilt WiFi and install a USB WiFi, will this work?

I'm just wondering if I turn off the inbuilt WiFi does that mean *any* WiFi network connection is disabled in windows, or just that particular card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will work fine.

As you say, just turn off the internal Wi-Fi, the USB stick may well find the right drivers from Windows Update, if not, install the manufacturer supplied ones.

Comment: I've simply used the [Fn] [F2] to turn off the built-in wireless and then installed the newly purchased USB card. It's working fine.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working.